# set post author depending on condition via frontend post submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress cms and I allow users to post from frontend. There are three kinds of users. Myself as admin, a junior ( given a role of an author) and anyone from public as non-logged-in user. Currently if any non-logged-in user posts from frontend, I am assigned as an author with this code. Currently my `wp_insert_post` array looks something like this :

```
'post_title'    => $final_title,
'post_content'  => $about_stuff,
'post_status'   => 'draft',
'post_author'   => '20',
'post_type' => 'post',
 etc....
```

wherein my author id is '20'. All this works fine. Now, what I would like to achieve is when my junior logs-in and creates post in the frontend, I would like him to be the post author, and not me (as currently set). I understand that the post_author will need to be a variable example `$content_creator`. Given below is the code I have written till now, but I am confused how to put it together in order to achieve what I need. To be specific I am confused how do I make the variable $content_creator work with rest of the code.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 19 == $current_user->ID ) {
    'post_author' => '19';
    } else {
    'post_author' => '20',
    }
 }
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory and basic which says check if the user if logged in, if yes check the user-id. If user id equals 19 set `'post_author' => '19'` (user id of my junior) otherwise set the author as admin. Two things I wanted to ask, do I also need global $post before my code and should I be using another filter [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) instead. Please help.

Final scenario must be, when the admin or anyone else creates a post the post-author must be set as admin (me) but when my junior creates a post he must be set as the post-author. This would have been unnecessary if we were creating posts in the backend but due to some reason we prefer to create posts in frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple with wp_update_post. Although, now it works fine. Let me know if you find something funny. Here is the code I am using after wp_insert_post and did not make any change in the array.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 19 == $current_user->ID ) {

    $update_creator = array(
                'ID'          => $pid, //created post ID
                'post_author' => '19'
            );

    wp_update_post( $update_creator );
    }
}
```